# What are the exceptional key points of a CV that attracts the research grant commette's attention?

Tags: application, cv

I need to provide a CV in maximum of 2 pages for a research grant application. I understand that such CVs varies largely from person to person and mostly depends on the requirement. But I am wondering about the exceptional key points which attracts reviewer's attention, apart from the common points found in all CVs.

As per the experts' comments below, CVs vary according to the grant, the agency, country and the academic credentials. Does really it vary?

My understanding may be wrong, a CV represents a person. It never tells us what the applicant is looking for. For that purpose we provide cover letter, motivation letter, statement of purpose etc etc..

Comment: Same as for a resume: Edit. Reformat. Rephrase. Repeat that sequence . There's no magic here, just a deadly focus on discarding everything that doesn't help you enough to be worth keeping. Some would advise _one_ page, depending on where you are in your career and what the grant is; I don't have a strong opinion.

Comment: Which agency in which country? NSF, DoE, NIH, etc, in the US have specific formatting guidelines that are required, and NSF has a recent reputation for returning some grants without review for egregious violations.

Comment: To second the request for the country: If I am not mistaken, many of the things you are listing here would not be considered to belong into a CV at all in certain countries.

Comment: Your updated version makes the question too broad. The key points depend on the type of the grant, the agency, your country and your academic credentials.

Comment: @scaaahu , Thank you very much for your comments. I can't understand how CVs vary according to the grant, the agency, country and the academic credentials? I may be wrong, but In my opinion, CV represents a person. On contrary, CV never represents a person what he/she is looking for. For that purpose we provide other documents like cover letter, motivation letter, statement of proposal etc. etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had recent experience related to the subject, I would advise the following **measures**:

- Remove *sections*: objectives, current position (instead, several most recent positions should be listed in *Positions Held* or *Professional Experience* section), schools/events participated, personal profile, declaration.
- Remove/compress most/enough *details* from the other sections to fit content appropriately.

Specific advice for **removing/compressing details**:

---

- *research interests*: make this section brief by mentioning high-level domains of interest (detailed discussion of your research interests IMHO should be presented in your research statement document);
- *research experiences*: make this section brief or consider getting rid of it for good (more/all details can be provided via either research statement, or application/cover letter);
- *publications*: list only your most important publications (rather than most recent);
- *education details*: this section should be brief just to cover essential information;

---

- *scholarship and awards*: very brief, just titles and amounts;
- *technical skills*: brief;
- *invited as speakers/guests*: very brief (select most important, if many);
- *professional memberships*: brief (select most important, if many);
- *professional services*: I suggest removing this section, as not relevant to grant applications;
- *papers presented in conferences (selected only)*: select from the selection, if needed.

---

By applying the above-mentioned steps, you should be able to create an appropriate two-page CV (see horizontal rules above for a suggested layout). Good luck with your grant application!